# Twig Filters and Text Format Filters

Tags: 8, theming

I've implemented a custom Twig filter that wraps certain character sequences with a span. The span element didn't show up in the front end until I allowed it in the text format for the field in question (via `Limit allowed HTML tags...`), so it seems that Twig filters are applied before text format filters. For my current use case, it seems like it would make more sense to run Twig filters *after* text format filters. Assuming I'm understanding this correctly, is there a reason this is the intended behavior? And if so, is there a way to change when Twig filters are applied to a field/format?

Comment: I do not at all think that these two things are related. So it might be some caching?

Comment: It's definitely not related to caching, and while the two types of text filtering and different, they're clearly related. I've confirmed that the `Limit allowed HTML tags` filter is applied after the Twig filter. While there are probably circumstances where that's desirable, it would be nice to be able to change the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this by running the field through the `render` filter first, then my custom filter. The text format filters are applied at the render stage, so now the custom filter runs after them. The finished order is:

```
{{ field | render | custom_filter }}
```